# Nuxt middleware creating infinite redirects

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a middleware which checks at what step of registration the user is in and based on that I redirect user to appropiate page. Here is my middleware code:

```
export default function ({app, redirect, route}) {
    let auth = app.$auth;
    console.log('step checks middleware');

    if(auth.loggedIn) {
        console.log('[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in');
        console.log(`[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed ${auth.user.step_completed}`);

        if(auth.user.step_completed === '1') {
            console.log(`[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'`);
            if(route.fullPath === '/registration/2') {
                console.log(`[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Routing to /registration/2. No redirect.`);
            } else {
                console.log(`[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to /registration/2.`);
                return redirect('/registration/2');
            }
        }

        if(auth.user.step_completed === '3') {
            console.log(`[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/3'`);
            if(route.fullPath === '/registration/3') {
                console.log(`[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Routing to /registration/3. No redirect.`);
            } else {
                console.log(`[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to /registration/3.`);
                return redirect('/registration/3');
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But this is creating a infinite loop of redirection.

**Output**

```
================= Step checks middleware ==================  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed 1  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to /registration/2.  
  nuxt:render Rendering url /registration/2 +2s  
Making request to /api/me  
Making request to /api/web/interest_categories  
================= Step checks middleware ==================  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed 1  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Routing to /registration/2. No redirect.  
  nuxt:render Rendering url / +1s  
Making request to /api/me  
Making request to /api/web/interest_categories  
================= Step checks middleware ==================  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed 1  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to /registration/2.  
  nuxt:render Rendering url /registration/2 +1s  
Making request to /api/me  
Making request to /api/web/interest_categories  
================= Step checks middleware ==================  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed 1  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Routing to /registration/2. No redirect.  
  nuxt:render Rendering url / +1s  
Making request to /api/me  
Making request to /api/web/interest_categories  
================= Step checks middleware ==================  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed 1  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to /registration/2.  
  nuxt:render Rendering url /registration/2 +1s  
Making request to /api/me  
Making request to /api/web/interest_categories  
================= Step checks middleware ==================  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed 1  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Routing to /registration/2. No redirect.  
  nuxt:render Rendering url / +1s  
Making request to /api/me  
Making request to /api/web/interest_categories  
================= Step checks middleware ==================  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed 1  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to /registration/2.  
  nuxt:render Rendering url /registration/2 +1s  
Making request to /api/me  
Making request to /api/web/interest_categories  
================= Step checks middleware ==================  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed 1  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Routing to /registration/2. No redirect.  
  nuxt:render Rendering url / +1s  
Making request to /api/me  
Making request to /api/web/interest_categories  
================= Step checks middleware ==================  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed 1  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to /registration/2.  
  nuxt:render Rendering url /registration/2 +1s  
Making request to /api/me  
Making request to /api/web/interest_categories  
================= Step checks middleware ==================  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User logged in  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] User step completed 1  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Should be redirected to '/registration/2'  
[StepChecks Middleware][Info] Routing to /registration/2. No redirect.
```

And this goes on. I can not figure out why this issues is happening. Initailly I did not have a check for the current path check `if(route.fullPath === '/registration/2')`, in that case rest of the pages were working fine but navigated to `/registration/2` from registration page it was creating infinite loop of redirection.

Comment: It doesnt look like a problem is in the code you posted. Looks like something elsewhere do a redirect to / . Are u using @nuxt/auth module ?

Comment: @Aldarund  yes. in fact the issue seems to be from @nuxt/auth 's middleware. which is redirecting to / from `/registration/2`.  For now I've removed it and manually checking if user is authenticated on mounted hook. Any Idea why it is happening/

Comment: Which version of nuxt auth? Is it happening only in firefox or in chrome too?

Comment: @Aldarund, on both firefox and chrome. I'm using version 4.5.1

Comment: im also experience it now,.. do you have updates for solution for this @SayantanDas

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late here, but anyway.

I faced the same problem and i looked for an answer for many hours.

My solution to the problem was adding an

```
if (process.server) { ... }
```

block inside my middleware function since in the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context#redirect) it is stated that "it's not possible to use redirect or error in client-side Nuxt plugin due to hydration errors".